# How to catch HttpException with Retrofit and RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to catch HTTP exception so I can handle it and display proper error messages for users.

I am using Retrofit with RxJava 2. I am catching throwable, but it always goes to else case, instead of if case.

```
Disposable disposable = agreementsRepository.getAgreementAppointments(agreementId, appointmentId)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        agreementAppointment -> {
          if (Constants.APPOINTMENT_INITIAL.equals(appointmentType)) {
            view.displayInitialAppointmentInfo(agreementAppointment.getServiceAppointment());
          } else {
            view.displayRecurringAppointmentInfo(agreementAppointment.getServiceAppointment());
          }
        },
        throwable -> {
          if(throwable instanceof HttpException) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Http exception");
          } else {
            view.handleError(throwable);
          } }
    );
```

The server returns HTTP 500 exception and I am trying to catch it with throwable, but somehow it does not go to if statement.

What is the issue?

Comment: What stops you from checking the type of `throwable` in case of 500 error? Attach a debugger and check it or just print it via log.d.

Comment: I'd also go for the debugger and would add that you need to double check the full qualified name for the `HttpException`. It so happens there are more than one and you might be importing the wrong one.